How to convert React Components to PDF, for download, printing and file attachment via email
In my react code I'm using MUI5 to create my react components. As of now I'm using two buttons to print and download a pdf report, and of course the content of the pdf which can be viewed in this SCREENSHOT. The React components as shown in the first Screenshot have a parent
<Box ref={componentRef} id="pdf_vehicle_report_purchase_success">
When using Print PDF button i'm executing the following:
import { useReactToPrint } from 'react-to-print';

...

const handlePrint = useReactToPrint({
   content: () => componentRef.current,
   documentTitle: 'PDF Report',
   pageStyle: () => `
        @page { margin: 0mm; }
        @media print {
            ...
            #buttonPdfPrint {
                display: none;
            }
        }
    `
});

The above code is working fine:

Is using the react-to-print library to prepare and open a Print Preview window which renders the React Components into a document.
This allows me to either download or print the document.
Additional CSS is also applied(print icon not visible in this stage).
It also renders the content as text and not as IMAGE.

See image for reference:

For the download button i have a similar function but in this case im returning an iframe and passing it to generateAndSavePDF function. There im applying additional css to the iframe. and then printing the iframe:
const vehicleReportStyles2 = `
   ...
`;

const downloadPDF = useReactToPrint({
   content: () => componentRef.current,
   documentTitle: 'PDF Report',
   print: async (printIframe) => {
      await generateAndSavePDF(printIframe);
   }
});

const generateAndSavePDF = async (iFrame) => {
        const iframeDocument = iFrame.contentDocument || iFrame.contentWindow.document;

        // Inject CSS Styles of Vehicle Report to the iframe
        const styleElement = document.createElement('style');
        styleElement.appendChild(document.createTextNode(vehicleReportStyles2));
        iframeDocument.head.appendChild(styleElement);

        // Wait for styles to be applied
        await new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, 100));

        console.log(iframeDocument); //Returns an iframe with injected custom css

};

THE ISSUE:

Most of the libraries i have tried below is converting the iframe to an Image , or is completely entirely messing the design of the final result.

jsPDF
html2canvas
react-to-pdf
react-pdf
@react-pdf/renderer

REQUIRED SOLUTION:

I simply want to do the following:

Convert the React Components to a PDF which is not an image
Open Print Preview (already completed unless better solution is given)
Direct Download of the generated PDF
Store PDF to be sent as email attachment (perhaps in a variable or React.useState)

Any feedback on the above will be highly appreciated.

Did you ever find a solution for this? I presume with @react-pdf/renderer it wasn't rendering your styling properly? (because that library doesn't simply turn it into an image)

I ended up using @react-pdf/renderer. I used MUI to display my content on front end and simple html and css for the content that is rendered in @react-pdf/renderer

Thanks; I was hoping to avoid separate formatting, but might have to go that route as well.

yeap, is best approach that i can think for now, it works fine, but it takes double the time and need to modify both templates in case of design changes. but it works
